# Apache Velocity Combining Multiple AND/OR within a IF statement

Tags: velocity

I am a bit stumped with handling multiple and/or statements within an if statement. I'm hoping someone can help me out with this. The Velocity reference guide doesn't appear to address what I am trying to do.

I am working with an application in which I will be using public fields. I have to map an ID from a public field with a name. I have two components for my if statement. I have first an OR operand handling two values of a field. I then have another component to where an AND statement has to be combined.

Here is what I currently have:

```
      #if ($!myid == '21' && $!mytechno == 161)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;John Smith
      #elseif ($!myid == '21' && $!mytechno == 162)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Mickey Mouse
      #elseif ($!myid == '21' && $!mytechno == 164)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Jean Jones)
      #else<B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData

      #end
      #end
```

So this is working correctly so far. Basically I am checking the value of both the myID AND making sure that a mytechno has to exist. That way, it will populate that Tech2 field that I am referencing.

While this is all and good, I need to add in another myid value. Let's say that myID value is 10. I tried doing this

```
    #if ($!myid == '21' || $myid='10' && $!mytechno == 161)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;John Smith
      #elseif ($!myid == '21' || $myid='10' && $!mytechno == 162)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Mickey Mouse
      #elseif ($!myid == '21 || $myid='10'' && $!mytechno == 164)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Jean Jones)
      #else<B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData

      #end
      #end
```

What happens in this situation is that it checks the first statement and assumes it to be true since the myID matches the data that I am working with. So, if the mytechno is 164, it displays "John Smith" The logic fails to check the mytechno field.

I also tried this

```
      #if ($!myid == '21' || $myid='10') && ($!mytechno == 161)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;John Smith
      #elseif ($!myid == '21' || $myid='10') && ($!mytechno == 162)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Mickey Mouse
      #elseif ($!myid == '21 || $myid='10'') && ($!mytechno == 164)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Jean Jones)
      #else<B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData

      #end
      #end
```

That didn't work either. Can anyone offer any suggestions? Just to sum it up, it should be an OR statement combined with an AND statement. If this was SQL I could easily do this, just not sure with Velocity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found this out. So here is what I did

```
      #if (($!myid == '21' || $myid='10') && ($!mytechno == 161)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;John Smith
      #elseif (($!myid == '21' || $myid='10') && ($!mytechno == 162)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Mickey Mouse
      #elseif (($!myid == '21 || $myid='10'') && ($!mytechno == 164)
      <B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData<BR><BR>
      <B>Tech2</B>&nbsp;Jean Jones
      #else<B>Technologist:</B>&nbsp;$!MytechData

      #end
      #end
```

I still need to test further. But it looks like I had to include an extra set of parenthesis.

EDIT: I had to take out that extra parenthesis at the end. Otherwise, the extra parenthesis displayed on the application itself. Not sure why I had to remove it as I thought you had to put an extra set of parenthesis when enclosing data. At least that is how it works with SQL.